# This question relates to "What" and "Whose"

Tags: word-choice, difference

[Basically I want to know the names of all the teachers of X college so that I can choose what teacher would be perfect for me]

What teacher lectures are you providing?

Or

Whose teacher lectures are you providing?

Comment: Surely your choice will depend on the subjects being taught rather than the names of the teachers? I would ask "What courses are available at the college?"

Comment: I meant there were different teachers available for same subject. Some teachers teach better than others

Comment: But they must all be offering different courses in that subject; the college can't be paying different people to teach exactly the same thing.

Comment: "**Which** lecturers are teaching at the college?"

Comment: Since we don't know exactly who else are teaching in that college, shouldn't be there "What" instead of "Which" . When options are unknown we use what,  Correct me if I'm wrong. I'm basically a CA student. CA subjects are taught at private colleges where you have option to choose any teacher available at the college. Since I intended to take lectures online , I wanted  ask  college  representative on whatsapp that question.

Comment: Is that Chartered Accountancy? You could ask "What/which lecturers are offering courses?" (I agree with @WeatherVane that it feels odd to use _what_ when referring to people.)

Comment: I'll expand that to "Which lecturers are teaching what courses at the college?"

Answer (score 1):

Neither one of your sentences is quite correct. It is not common, and sounds odd, to refer to lectures as “teacher lectures.”

You could say, “Whose lectures are you providing?” This is correct because “Whose” already indicates a possessive.

If you don’t use “whose,” you would have to indicate the possessive. You could say “What (or Which) teacher’s lectures are you providing?” Note that I have added the possessive ‘s to “teacher.”